# Importing large amounts of data using MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

We created a import script which imports about 120GB of data into a MySQL database. The data is saved in a few hunderd directories (all are seperated databases). Each directory contains files with table structures and table data.

The issue being; it works on my local machine with a subset of the actual data, but when the import is ran on the server (Which takes a few days). Not all the tables are created (even tables that are tested locally). The odd thing is that the script, when ran on the server does not show any errors on the creation of the tables.

Here is on a high level how the script works:

1. Find all directories that represent a database
2. Create all databases
3. Per database loop through the tables: create table, fill table

Added the code on gist: https://gist.github.com/3349872

Comment: There is not nearly enough information for anyone to help you. But I recommend you use a more appropriate language for importing such a large amount of data into MySQL.

Comment: maybe some some setting with your [script execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), the rest is hard to figure out, without any code.

Comment: I agree with Martin that PHP is not the correct language to use here. Try something that's compiled, rather than interpreted.

Comment: What information would you require. I have no idea where to search for the problem so point me in a direction and I'll get the information. Secondly, I cant do anything about the chosen language.

Comment: @MihaiIorga the script did it amazingly good on execution time (okey a lot of resets) and memory management. Added the code on gist. The stackoverflow formatter could not handle it.

Comment: I saw you have `import.log`, are there missing also ?

Comment: If it is working on local, but remote, then I suggest to compare the php configrations, both local php.ini and remote php.ini.

Comment: @MihaiIorga there is indeed something weird with import.log it only saves the first line (remote) though all echos are written, correctly, to an output file (nohup.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auch, the problem was in the code. Amazingly stupid mistake.

When testing the code on a subset of all the files all table information and table content where available. When a table count not be created the function enters a logging statement and than returns. On the real data this was a the mistake because there are files with no data and no structure so after creating a few tables this creation of the tables of a certain database went wrong and did a return and so didn't create the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add more logging to see steps that succeded since you might be having problems with memory usage or execution times.

Why dont you create sql files from given CVS files and then just do normal importing in bash?

mysql -u root -ppassword db_something< db_user.sql